# Вывод таблицы на страницу через JS, без обновления самой страницы

Tags: javascript, php

Могу вывести таблицу непосредственно на форме, но нужно чтобы она выводилась только при нажатии на клавишу, а затем можно было вернуться к стартовой странице

```
<table border="0" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Позиция</th>
    <th>Имя</th>
    <th>Очки</th>
  </tr>
    <?php 
    require("processing.php");
    $db = new DB();
    $result = $db->selectAllScores();
    //$numrows = $result->num_rows;
    if($result){
    //  echo $result;
        $count = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>". $count ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['username'] ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['score'] ."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $count++;
            if($count == 11) {
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
   ?> 
</table>
```

Увы с JS дружу плохо, так и не разобрался что делать с выводом таблиц

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Ajax:

```js
$('#myActionButton').click(function(){
    $.post(
        "/скрипт/который/будет/добавлять/таблицу.php", 
        { myActionName: "Выполнить" } 
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myActionButton">Выполни</button>
```

Вынесите создание таблицы в отдельный файл и замените путь. Других путей для добавления таблицы без обновления нет.

Answer (score 1):

для этого необходимо сделать кнопку на странице, на нее повешать JS обработчик, который отправит AJAX запрос на сервер, на стороне сервера будет получена необходимая информация, сформируется тело таблицы и она вернется в ваш изначальный шаблон

Comment: А объяснить как не надо?